# Using Make Query Table to join featureclass with table using 2 fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, file-geodatabase, query-table

I would like to join a forest density table to a forest ownership featureclass  in a geodatabase based on two columns in each (TPO_Owner and County_Nm) so I can populate the Density column in the featureclass with forest residuals density values from the table.  Each county contains forested area assigned to 1 of 4 ownership types, and each ownership type in each county has a forest residuals density assigned to it.

[image: Forested Ownership featureclass table]
[image: Biomass Density table]

I assume the best method for a "join" like this is to use the Make Query Table tool.  I have tried the tool in ArcMap and ArcCatalog using ModelBuilder by selecting all the relevant fields in both tables, using the following expression:

'ID_forested_LU_ownership_by_county.TPO_Owner'= 'ID_forest_density.Owner_Type' AND 'ID_forest_density.County_Nm'= 'ID_forested_LU_ownership_by_county.County_Nm'

and using both "Use Key Field" and "Add Virtual Key Field" in different runs.  My problem is that the resulting table does not properly do a join based on the two columns in each table.  The resulting featureclass is 11 GB and creates every iteration of Forested Ownership.county + Forested Ownership.ownership type + ID Density.county + ID Density.ownership. And it doesn't even bring over the density values from the table!

[image: Forested Ownership Density table]

The files are in a file geodatabase.

How can I get the join (or an alternative approach) to work properly?

Comment: Is the data in an *enterprise* geodabase?  If so, please **edit** the question to specify which one (name, release, ...) and the versions of both ArcGIS Desktop and the geodabase.

Comment: where is the forest density table stored? in RDBMS?, geodatabase, flat file?

Comment: All the data (table and featureclass) is stored in a geodatabase.

Comment: in this case, I do not see why you are choosing to use the Make Query Tool. Have you considered completing a [Join](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About%20joining%20and%20relating%20tables). There are many tutorials on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3WLTN25d8Q)

Comment: is there some reason as to why you have chosen the Make Query Tool? This is generally useful when you require a 1:M or to reach into a separate database or when you want to utilize full SQL functions.

Comment: What ***kind*** of geodatabase?  File geodatabase?  Personal geodatabase?  The underlying software is the SQL provider, and each is *different*.   Please ***always*** [edit] the question in response to questions for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to hide important details in the comments.